# Brownian Bridge with pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have found the following clever code [Brownion Motion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59926/how-to-draw-brownian-motions-in-tikz-pgf) here to plot a brownian motion:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}


% Create a function for generating inverse normally distributed numbers using the Box–Muller transform
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{invgauss}{2}{%
  \pgfmathparse{sqrt(-2*ln(#1))*cos(deg(2*pi*#2))}%
}
% Code for brownian motion
\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{
    table/.cd,
    brownian motion/.style={
        create on use/brown/.style={
            create col/expr accum={
                (\coordindex>0)*(
                    max(
                        min(
                            invgauss(rnd,rnd)*0.1+\pgfmathaccuma,
                            \pgfplots@brownian@max
                        ),
                        \pgfplots@brownian@min
                    )
                ) + (\coordindex<1)*\pgfplots@brownian@start
            }{\pgfplots@brownian@start}
        },
        y=brown, x expr={\coordindex},
        brownian motion/.cd,
        #1,
        /.cd
    },
    brownian motion/.cd,
            min/.store in=\pgfplots@brownian@min,
        min=-inf,
            max/.store in=\pgfplots@brownian@max,
            max=inf,
            start/.store in=\pgfplots@brownian@start,
        start=0
}
\makeatother
%

% Initialise an empty table with a certain number of rows
\pgfplotstablenew{201}\loadedtable % How many steps?


\begin{document}
\pgfplotsset{
        no markers,
        xmin=0,
        enlarge x limits=false,
        scaled y ticks=false,
        ymin=-1, ymax=1
}
\tikzset{line join=bevel}
\pgfmathsetseed{3}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
   \addplot table [brownian motion] {\loadedtable};
   \addplot table [brownian motion] {\loadedtable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But i'm not good enough in LaTeX/pgfplot/Tikz to understand how and where i have to change it to get a Brownian bridge instead that brownian motion.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Does the following help? If `B(t)` is Brownian motion for `t\in [0,1]`, then `BB(t)=B(t)-t*B(1)` forms a Brownian Bridge on that interval. Usually, one is interested in standardized Brownian motion, i.e., a Wiener process, for which `W(1)\sim N(0,1)`. To generate sample paths of a Wiener process, start by normalizing the x-axis values to range from 0 to 1 instead of from 0 to n and by standardizing the variance of the increments so that `Var(B(1))=1`. (You may set `B(0)=0`.)

Comment: Thx i already know the mathematical definition of the BB. But my skills makes me unable to understand and change the previous Tikz code 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are waiting for Tikz help, here is an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), that might be simpler to follow / adapt.  This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you have to compile it with `lualatex`.

I've followed some of the discussion in [this stats answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/305058/38310).

[image]

The blue line is a regular brownian random walk, where the y-value is incremented by a normal deviate each time.  The red line is the brownian bridge, which is derived from the regular walk by subtracting an appropriately weighted proportion of the final y-value.

To make the example concrete, I used 200 samples and a fixed random seed, so that the final value of the walk `w[n]` was 17.8543 -- each point of the red line `bb[i]` is then `w[i] - (i/n) * (b - w[n])`.  This means that `bb[n]` is `w[n] - (n/n) * (b - w[n]) = b` as desired.

Here is the code. Compile this with `lualatex` to get a PDF that looks like the image above.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\mplibshowlog{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
% randomseed := uniformdeviate infinity;
randomseed := 778.58453;
beginfig(1);
% parameters: n number of samples, a = start, b = target
numeric n, a, b; n = 200; a = b = 0;

% x and y scales
numeric u, v; u = 2; v = 8;

% base line
draw ((0, a) -- (n, b)) xscaled u yscaled v;

% w[] is the regular brownian random walk
% bb[] is the brownian bridge
numeric w[], bb[]; 
w0 = a;
for i=1 upto n: 
  w[i] = w[i-1] + normaldeviate;
endfor
for i=0 upto n:
  bb[i] = w[i] + (i/n) * (b - w[n]);
endfor

draw ((0, a) for i=1 upto n: -- (i, w[i]) endfor) 
    xscaled u yscaled v withcolor blue; 
draw ((0, a) for i=1 upto n: -- (i, bb[i]) endfor) 
    xscaled u yscaled v withcolor red; 

label.rt("$(" & decimal n & "," & decimal w[n] & ")$", (n*u, w[n]*v));

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the `randomseed` trick at the start, see this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262544/15036)

Comment: Yes that's indeed something much more readable for me. And how do you add ticks and  and axes and legends with metapost?

Comment: Follow the link at the top for Metapost tutorials etc, or have a look at Chapter 16 of my [Drawing with Metapost](https://ctan.org/pkg/drawing-with-metapost?lang=en) document, now available on CTAN; that chapter shows you how to plot functions, draw axes, make labels, etc.

Comment: Ok that's much better than the default documentation i have found so far on metapost yesterday. Thanks a lot i will try.